# Copy worksheet columns with particular header into a different columns on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I can find the columns on the first worksheet with particular data header.  Then want to copy each of these columns onto another worksheet, different columns.  This ends up skipping much of the data I don’t need on the first worksheet.  Data from one experiment to another changes so I need a general macro.

Have search with Stackoverflow and tried several variations of the following:

```
Sub copy_pressure_columns()
Dim oSWksht     As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oDWksht     As Excel.Worksheet
Dim c As Range, v
Dim k As Range, j
Set oSWksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("hscth_exp_50g_wall_jan20")
Set oDWksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
j = 3
For Each c In Application.Intersect(oSWksht.Rows(2), oSWksht.UsedRange)
  v = Trim(c.Value)
  If v Like "P.#" Or v Like "P.##" Then
    Debug.Print v & " found at " & c.Column & _
                 " on '" & c.Parent.Name & "'"
    Debug.Print " from column " & c.Column & _
                 " to column '" & j & "'"
     Sheets(oSWksht).Columns(c.Column).Copy Destination:=Sheets(oDWksht).Columns(j.Column)
    j = j + 1
  End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
c.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=oDWksht.Cells(1, j)
```

If it's still skipping data then it would help to provide and example of something which should get copied but doesn't

Comment: Crashes on new Copy statement with error 13           With my limited knowledge I would assume there is a problem dealing with the ranges on each of the columns

Comment: Sorry bad copy-paste: fixed above.